# GWT minimize generated HTML code

Tags: html, gwt, minimize

I want to reduce size of HTML code, that is generated, for example, by GWT [VerticalPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html). How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Widgets don't generate HTML, they manipulate DOM elements. There's nothing to *minify*.

If what bugs you is that `VerticalPanel` uses a `<table>` then, well, don't use a `VerticalPanel`. In many cases, a `FlowPanel` will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit unsure about your goal.

In order for the GWT lib to accommodate all possible uses of VerticalPanel, a certain amount of HTML code is needed. I find that compiled GWT code is very compact.

I do not think there is a way to reduce the amount of output HTML.